# Activating a Signal from models to create a directory folder

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

Hope all is well. I was hoping if i could pick someone's brain.
I am attempting to create a folder everytime a board is created in the App module. Files will be uploaded through other means. However I need a folder destination with the the Board Name created at Board Save. I have tried to call the signals file as a regular function but end up with countless errors. The signals function works great if i just call it outside django.

I would like that everytime a User saves a Board, a folder is added to a "User_Files" Directory. I am aware that a node.js would do this job. Just not there yet.

I can connect a signal from the model to signals but get a

```
"python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/Desktop/Gear/Thelium Backups/JUPYTER_THELIUM/thelium/env/thelium/boards/models.py", line 70, in <module>
    signals.post_save.connect(mkdir_board(Board, sender=Board))
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/signals.py", line 28, in connect
    weak=weak, dispatch_uid=dispatch_uid,
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/signals.py", line 23, in _lazy_method
    return partial_method(sender)
  File "/Users/zeitgeist/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 90, in connect
    assert callable(receiver), "Signal receivers must be callable."
AssertionError: Signal receivers must be callable.
```

I cannot seem for the life of me figure out a work-around. Please help iv poured over the internet for a couple days trying to figure this out. Can anyone see the problem with my code?
Thanks all in advance!

Here is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from pathlib import Path
import errno
import os
from django.db.models import signals
from django.dispatch import Signal
from .signals import mkdir_board

User = get_user_model()

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="owned_boards"
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="boards")
      
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def save(
        self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        is_new = self.pk is None
        super().save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
        if is_new:
            self.members.add(self.owner)

    def send_signal(self):
        signals.send_robust(sender=self.__class__, instance=self)
    
signals.post_save.connect(mkdir_board(Board, sender=Board))

class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    board = models.ForeignKey("Board", related_name="labels", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["name", "board"], name="unique_name_board")
        ]
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import IntegrityError
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import ValidationError
from accounts.serializers import BoardMemberSerializer
from .models import Board, Task, Column, Label, Comment
from pathlib import Path
import errno
import os

User = get_user_model()


class BoardModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if self.context["request"].user not in validated_data["board"].members.all():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Must be a member of the board!")
        return super().create(validated_data)
    

class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ["id", "name", "owner"]
```

signals.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiverimport Board 
import errno
import os


from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
path = "boards/User_Files/"

@receiver(post_save)
def mkdir_board(self, sender, **kwargs):
    
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
        except OSError as exc:  # Python ≥ 2.5
            if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
                pass
                    # possibly handle other errno cases here, otherwise finally:
            else:
                raise
```

admin.py

```
from adminsortable.admin import SortableAdmin
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Board, Label


class LabelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["name", "board"]
    list_filter = ["board"]
    search_fields = ["name"]

    class Meta:
        model = Label


admin.site.register(Label, LabelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Board)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class BoardsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "boards"

    def ready(self):
        """ Executes whatever is necessary when the application is ready. """
        from . import signals
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind! figured it out!

> ```
> @receiver(post_save, sender = Board) 
> def mkdir_board(sender, instance ,**kwargs):
>     rel_path = "boards/User_Files/_{}".format(instance.id)
>     try:
>         os.makedirs(rel_path)
>     except OSError as exc:  # Python ≥ 2.5
>         if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
>             pass
>                 # possibly handle other errno cases here, otherwise finally:
>         else:
>             raise
> ```

Now works like a charm! Hope this helps someone